# sapper/svelte with fomantic-ui and fontawesome-free

Tags: css, font-awesome, svelte, sapper, fomantic-ui

I'm starting a project with Sapper (https://sapper.svelte.dev/) / Svelte (https://svelte.dev/) and my client wants to use Fomantic-UI as a CSS framework (https://fomantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html).

I don't have found on the net, examples of how to do this. Would someone help me do this? Including the  correctly configuration for fontawesome-free icons with fomantic-ui?

About the Fomantic-UI, i did:

```sh
npx degit "sveltejs/sapper-template#rollup" frontend
cd frontend
npm install --save-dev node-sass svelte-preprocess autoprefixer
npm i fomantic-ui-sass
```

After that, I changed the `rollup.config.js` includind this lines:

```js
...
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
...
const preprocess = sveltePreprocess({
  scss: {
    includePaths: ['src']
  },
  postcss: {
    plugins: [require('autoprefixer')]
  }
});
...
export default {
  client: {
    ...
    svelte({
        ...,
          preprocess,
        ...
    })
    ...
  server: {
    ...
    svelte({
        ...,
          emitCss: true,
          preprocess,
        ...
    })
    ...
```

I wrote a file `svelte.config.js`:

```js
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess');
module.exports = {
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
    scss: {
      includePaths: ['src']
    },
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require('autoprefixer')]
    }
  })
};
```

I created a directory `src/style`with one file `global.css`:

```
$theme-folder: 'default' !default;
$image-path: '#{$theme-folder}/assets/images' !default;
$font-path: '#{$theme-folder}/assets/fonts' !default;

@import '../../node_modules/fomantic-ui-sass/src/utils/all';
@import '../../node_modules/fomantic-ui-sass/src/variables'; // default theme variables
@import '../../node_modules/fomantic-ui-sass/src/semantic.scss'; // Semantic-UI SCSS
```

In `src/routes/_layout.svelte`, I called the `global.scss`:

```js
<svelte:head>
  <style src="../style/global.scss"></style>
</svelte:head>
```

And I copied the folder `./node_modules/fomantic-ui-sass/src/themes/default/assets` to `./static/default/assets`

And the icons is showing now correctly.

Is this the best solution?

Comment: I think using vite bundler seems to be better.